# Excel chart to only show month when there is data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I update a table often, which powers a chart. It's a pain when after I enter the information into the table, I have to then fiddle with the chart and give it new dimensions so it displays the information I want.

For an example, this means for this data

[image]

If I select the 'table', and get Excel to make a line chart, it displays this chart (essentially showing everything I've asked it too, which makes sense!)

[image]

I would, with the same selection as per the screen shot above, if the chart showed like:

[image]

As you can see, I only want it to show the month if there is data (in other words, I only want to show the entry in the X Axis if there is corresponding data in the Y axis). I could easily enter 0 into my table to make it clear that the value is 0, but right now, the value for April and May is essentially null (or blank).

Is this possible in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Select the entire table (including the unused lines!), and apply Autofilter.

Now, when you set the autofilter on one of your data columns to show "everything except blank", the graph will also change to show only the lines with data.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use defined names for ranges. For `Data1` you can use either:

```
=$B$2:XLOOKUP(TRUE,N(+$B:$B)<>0,$B:$B,,,-1)
```

or (it depends on Excel version):

```
=$B$2:INDEX($B:$B,LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER($B:$B),ROW($B:$B)))
```

For `Data2` you can use analogous formulas with `C` replacing `B` or:

```
=OFFSET(Data1,,1)
```

These names should be used in chart definition but you must use a filename before defined name e.g. for `Series1`

```
=Lin_chart.xlsx!Data1
```